Unknown error - Python Multithreading Issue
I am trying to perform multithreading in python. I am not new to python but only to the concept of Qt Threading specifically. Please find a sample code below:
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tekwfm
import scipy
import plotly.express as px
import sys
import plotly.io as pio
from datetime import datetime as dt
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, uic

class ParameterWorker(QtCore.QObject):

    datasignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object,object,object)
    finishedsignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    
    def __init__(self,prefix,directory,factor,testvoltage):
        super().__init__()
        self.prefix = prefix
        self.directory = directory
        self.factor = factor
        self.testvoltage = testvoltage
        self.tmatrix = None
        self.vloadmatrix = None
        self.vopmatrix = None
        self.curmatrix = None
        self.reqdata = None
        self.pospeaks = None
        self.negpeaks = None
    
    def run(self):
        # Define the three channels
        voltage_load_file = os.path.join(self.directory, f"{self.prefix}_ch1.wfm")
        voltage_output_file = os.path.join(self.directory, f"{self.prefix}_ch2.wfm")
        current_file = os.path.join(self.directory, f"{self.prefix}_ch3.wfm")
        pospeaks = dict()
        negpeaks = dict()
    
        if os.path.exists(voltage_load_file) and os.path.exists(voltage_output_file) and os.path.exists(
                current_file):
            volts_load, tstart, tscale, tfrac, tdatefrac, tdate = tekwfm.read_wfm(voltage_load_file)
            volts_output, _, _, _, _, _ = tekwfm.read_wfm(voltage_output_file)
            currents, _, _, _, _, _ = tekwfm.read_wfm(current_file)
    
            toffset = tscale * tfrac
            samples, frames = volts_load.shape
            tstop = samples * tscale + tstart
            tmatrix = np.linspace(tstart + toffset, tstop + toffset, num=samples, endpoint=False)
    
            torig = pd.DataFrame(data=tmatrix)
            orwo, ocol = torig.shape
            windowparam = (ocol // self.factor, ocol // self.factor)
            tmatrix = torig.T.rolling(window=windowparam[0], step=windowparam[1], center=True).mean().T.dropna(
                axis=1)
            trow, tcol = tmatrix.shape
            tmatrix.columns = np.arange(tcol)
            self.tmatrix = tmatrix
    
            vloadorig = pd.DataFrame(data=volts_load)
            vloadmatrix = vloadorig.T.rolling(window=windowparam[0], step=windowparam[1],
                                              center=True).mean().T.dropna(
                axis=1)
            vloadmatrix.columns = np.arange(tcol)
            self.vloadmatrix = vloadmatrix
    
            voporig = pd.DataFrame(data=volts_output)
            vopmatrix = voporig.T.rolling(window=windowparam[0], step=windowparam[1], center=True).mean().T.dropna(
                axis=1)
            vopmatrix.columns = np.arange(tcol)
            self.vopmatrix = vopmatrix
    
            # Current specific calculations
            curorig = pd.DataFrame(data=currents)
            curmatrix = curorig.T.rolling(window=windowparam[0], step=windowparam[1], center=True).mean().T.dropna(
                axis=1)
            curmatrix.columns = np.arange(tcol)
            self.curmatrix = curmatrix
    
            self.reqdata = pd.DataFrame(
                data={"fftime": torig[0], "ffvload": vloadorig[0], "ffvop": voporig[0], "ffcur": curorig[0],
                      "lftime": torig.iloc[:, -1], "lfvload": vloadorig.iloc[:, -1], "lfvop": voporig.iloc[:, -1],
                      "lfcur": curorig.iloc[:, -1]})
    
            for column in self.reqdata.columns:
                if column in ["ffcur", "lfcur"]:
                    vfactor = -12
                    hfactorpos = 0.055
                    hfactorneg = 0.78125
                    prom = 0.5
                else:
                    vfactor = 1
                    prom = 1
                    hfactorpos = 1.4
                    hfactorneg = 2.8
                if column not in ["fftime", "lftime"]:
                    ind1, _ = scipy.signal.find_peaks(vfactor * self.reqdata[column], prominence=prom,
                                                      height=hfactorpos * self.testvoltage)
                    ind2, _ = scipy.signal.find_peaks(-1 * vfactor * self.reqdata[column], prominence=prom,
                                                      height=hfactorneg * self.testvoltage)
                    if column in ["ffcur", "lfcur"]:
                        pospeaks[column] = ind2
                        negpeaks[column] = ind1
                    else:
                        pospeaks[column] = ind1
                        negpeaks[column] = ind2
            self.pospeaks = pospeaks
            self.negpeaks = negpeaks
    
            self.datasignal.emit(self.reqdata,self.pospeaks,self.negpeaks)
        self.finishedsignal.emit()


class MainCalculations(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, waveform=0, testvoltage=1000, factor=12):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = uic.loadUi("measurementui.ui",self)
        self.ch1_params = None
        self.ch2_params = None
        self.ch3_params = None
        self.vloadmatrix = None
        self.vopmatrix = None
        self.curmatrix = None
        self.directory = os.getcwd()  # Path to wfm files
        self.prefix = "Tek00" + f"{waveform}"  # e.g. "Tek000" of "Tek000_ch1.wfm"
        self.decimal_places = 2  # Number of decimal places in Excel file
        self.factor = factor
        self.testvoltage = testvoltage
        self.pospeaks = None
        self.negpeaks = None
        self.reqdata = None
        self.params = None
    
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.start_parameter_calculations)
    
    def start_parameter_calculations(self):
        thread = QtCore.QThread()
        pworker = ParameterWorker(self.prefix,self.directory,self.factor,self.testvoltage)
        pworker.datasignal.connect(lambda reqdata,pospeaks,negpeaks: self.get_parameters(reqdata,pospeaks,negpeaks))
        pworker.finishedsignal.connect(thread.quit)
        pworker.moveToThread(thread)
        thread.pworker = pworker
        thread.started.connect(pworker.run)
        thread.start()

    def get_parameters(self,reqdata,pospeaks,negpeaks):
        self.reqdata = reqdata
        self.pospeaks = pospeaks
        self.negpeaks = negpeaks
        maxlist = list()
        posamplist = list()
        minlist = list()
        negamplist = list()
        poswidthlist = list()
        negwidthlist = list()

        a = dt.now()
        for key1, key2 in zip(self.pospeaks.keys(), self.negpeaks.keys()):
            maxlist.append(max(self.reqdata[key1][self.pospeaks[key1]]))
            posamplist.append(np.mean(self.reqdata[key1][self.pospeaks[key1]]))
            poswidthlist.append(
                self.reqdata["fftime"][self.pospeaks[key1]].iloc[-1] - self.reqdata["fftime"][self.pospeaks[key1]].iloc[
                    0])
            poswidthlist.append(
                self.reqdata["lftime"][self.pospeaks[key1]].iloc[-1] - self.reqdata["lftime"][self.pospeaks[key1]].iloc[
                    0])
            minlist.append(min(self.reqdata[key2][self.negpeaks[key2]]))
            negamplist.append(np.mean(self.reqdata[key2][self.negpeaks[key2]]))
            negwidthlist.append(
                self.reqdata["fftime"][self.negpeaks[key2]].iloc[-1] - self.reqdata["fftime"][self.negpeaks[key2]].iloc[
                    0])
            negwidthlist.append(
                self.reqdata["lftime"][self.negpeaks[key2]].iloc[-1] - self.reqdata["lftime"][self.negpeaks[key2]].iloc[
                    0])
        b = dt.now()
        print("Time to execute calculations: " + str(b - a))

        posmaxval = (maxlist)
        posmeanval = (posamplist)
        negminval = (minlist)
        negmeanval = (negamplist)
        poswidth = (poswidthlist)
        negwidth = (negwidthlist)

        self.params = (posmaxval,posmeanval,negminval,negmeanval,poswidth,negwidth,interphaseval)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainCalculations()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


I have tried debugging the code in Pycharm and it just works fine with the print statement working just fine in the get_parameters(...) function. However, when I run it without debugging and click the respective push button in the UI, I get the following error:
Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
I have tried line by line debugging and yet there is no error anywhere thrown. I figured that this should be a threading issue. Coud anyone please help me on this?
EDIT: After re-running the script on the terminal, I got the following exact error message:


Most IDEs are not capable of displaying the full traceback, try to run the code in a terminal or prompt and eventually [edit] your post by providing relevant output.

@musicamante I just edited the post again with the right output. Would you happen to have an idea how this could be happening? I have linked the finishedsignal emission from the ParameterWorker Class instance to be triggered only upon the end of the run() code in there

The reason is simple, and a basic search about that error should suffice: the QThread object gets garbage collected because you're not creating a persistent reference to it. Change to something like self.workerThread = QThread() (avoid overwriting self.thread, since it's an existing function of all QObjects). Alternatively, change to QThread(self), but you should also ensure that the object is deleted once finished, so connect the finished signal of the QThread to its deleteLater.
